# @JoinTable() Nullable:False in typeorm

Tags: join, swagger, nestjs, decorator, typeorm

Somebody knows if is possible add the nullable property in @jointable() decorator?

```
 @ManyToMany(() => Country, (country) => country.continents, {
    nullable: false, // example
    cascade: ['insert', 'update'],
  })
  @JoinTable()
  Countries: Country[];
```

This is an example about what i want to do and i don't know why it doesn't works